# password_reset_confirm, sensitive_post_parameters didn't receive an HttpRequest

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-authentication

I'm coding a password reset functionality with `DRF`,

All works fine, but I get this error:

```
Django Version: 1.8.3
Exception Type: AssertionError
Exception Value:    
sensitive_post_parameters didn't receive an HttpRequest. If you are decorating a classmethod, be sure to use @method_decorator.
```

this is code launches the error:

```
class RecoveryPasswordConfirm(APIView):
    """
    API endpoint for recovery password
    """
    serializer_class = UpdatePasswordUserSelializer
    permission_classes = (AllowAny, )

    def post(self, request, uidb64=None, token=None):
        response = password_reset_confirm(
            request,
            template_name='',
            uidb64=uidb64,
            token=token,
            post_reset_redirect=reverse('password_reset_done'))

        return Response({}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

I don't know that more I should do.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you remembering to set up the view in your `urls.py` as `RecoveryPasswordConfirm.as_view()`?

Comment: @KevinBrown yes, when call `RecoveryPasswordConfirm` with a post request catch it, but `password_reset_confirm` returns error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see where `sensitive_post_parameters` is used in your code, it should be somewhere in `password_reset_confirm`.

Most likely problem is because DRF uses it's own request class that wraps original HttpRequest expected by django.
See [more details here](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/2768)

Try to use `request._request` to pass original django request.

```
response = password_reset_confirm(
    request._request,
```

Comment: `request._request` works, thanks. just in time!, again thanks